# Issues running my React Application with Webpack

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack, es6-promise

This code is my webpack.config.js file.

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "./dist"),
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        filename: "index_bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./src/index.html"
        })
    ],
    devServer: {
        publicPath: '/dist/'
    }
};
```

[image: I']

Attached is my error message.

I've tried reinstalling some packages and modifying this config file from the starterkit but to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you configure the `.babelrc` file?

Comment: @Thinker What's that? How and where should I do that?

Comment: add a file called `.babelrc` in your root folder where the webpack file is placed and add these line `{"presets":["env", "react"]}` and run again

Comment: @Thinker It still doesnt work. This image is the error message! 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rRd1Yg-8vtp7wm-DkcxxGIE-MEWr8hTI/view?usp=sharing